# Recursive function using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data:

```
dat <- tibble(
         day = 200:210,
         x = sample(-10:10, size = 11,replace = T))
```

I have a variable `y` with initial value of 2. I want to calculate the final value of `y` by adding x to y in a given time step following 
the following notation:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] + x
```

If I did this:

```
y <- 5
dat %>% mutate(y = y + x)
```

It adds y to each x.

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
    day     x     y
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1   200     4     9
2   201     3     8
3   202    -4     1
4   203    -7    -2
5   204    -3     2
6   205     1     6
7   206    -5     0
8   207    -1     4
9   208    -4     1
10  209    -2     3
11  210     4     9

The answer should be:

  # A tibble: 11 x 3
    day     x     y
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1   200     4     9
2   201     3     12
3   202    -4     8
4   203    -7     1
5   204    -3     -2
6   205     1     -1
7   206    -5     -6
8   207    -1     -7
9   208    -4     -11
10  209    -2     -13
11  210     4     -9
```

How do I achive this using dplyr package? Or any other method that is quick and fast.

**EDIT**

If I want to impose a condition such that y cannot exceed 10 or be negative .If it exceeds 10, make it 10 and if it is negative, make it zero.
How do I achieve this:

A tibble: 11 x 3

```
      day     x     y     y1
  1   200     4     9     9
  2   201     3     12    10
  3   202    -4     8     6
  4   203    -7     1     0 
  5   204    -3     -2    0
  6   205     1     -1    0
  7   206    -5     -6    0
  8   207    -1     -7    0  
  9   208    -4     -11   0
  10  209    -2     -13   0
  11  210     4     -9    0
```

Comment: the command you are looking for: `y[i-1]` is `lag(y)`

Comment: You can try `dat %>% mutate(y = accumulate(x[-n()], ~ .x + .y, .init = 5))`

Comment: This does it. I do not understand what (x[-n()] is doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We could use `accumulate` from `purrr`.  With `accumulate`, do the recursive `sum` of 'x' elements while initiating with a value of 5 (`.init = 5`) and remove the first element of `accumulate` output (`[-1]`)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
     mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~ .x + .y, .init = 5)[-1])
# A tibble: 11 x 3
#     day     x      y
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1   200     4   9.00
# 2   201     3  12.0 
# 3   202    -4   8.00
# 4   203    -7   1.00
# 5   204    -3 - 2.00
# 6   205     1 - 1.00
# 7   206    -5 - 6.00
# 8   207    -1 - 7.00
# 9   208    -4 -11.0 
#10   209    -2 -13.0 
#11   210     4 - 9.00
```

---

A similar approach in `base R` would be

```
dat$y <- Reduce(function(u, v)  u + v , dat$x, init = 5, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
dat$y
#[1]   9  12   8   1  -2  -1  -6  -7 -11 -13  -9
```

Comment: Very clever solution. Thank you

Comment: `~ .x + .y` I cannot get my head around this one. I am trying to read the purrr document but not sure what exactly this bit is doing

Comment: @KS89 Imagine that there are two values you are doing the sum i.e. one you already summed it i.e. 'y' and the other the next value of 'x'

Comment: @KS89  You will understand the `.x` and .`y` if you `print` it i.e. `dat %>%
     mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~ {
                      print(.x);
                      print(.y);
                      .x + .y;
                      }, .init = 5)[-1])`

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I have also edited the question now since I realized I need to impose some conditions on top of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165424/discussion-between-ks89-and-akrun).

Comment: @KS89  That should go as a separate question as it is unrelated to the above

Comment: Okay. Let me post it as a separate question

Comment: @KS89  Thanks, it needs a bit of effort from the current solution to get there.

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% mutate(y = 5 + cumsum(x))
```

or, with your extra conditions

```
df %>% mutate(y = (5 + cumsum(x)) %>% pmin(10) %>% pmax(0))
```

Comment: Thanks.If a y is converted to 10, the value of 10 should be added in the next x. For e.g. for the first 3 x's (4,3,-4) leads to y = (9, 12,8) which your solution converts to (9,10,8). However, since 12 is converted to 10, 10 should be used to add to -4 and the answer should be (9,10,6). I hope this is clear.